# Connecting tablet to wired only network

Tags: windows-8, router, printing, wired-networking

I have a wired only network through a switch which connects two computers and two printers. I want to print from with my tablet.  I have a Samsung tablet that does not have an wired RJ45 network adapter or port, only USB ports.  I have tried connecting a wireless router into the network but without  broadband connection, I still haven't been able to connect my Samsung tablet satisfactorily to the network - basically just to share the printers (alas they are not WiFi printers either.. My tablet has WiFi but no data sim, even with the router connected which tablet appears to connect to (but says limited connectivity) so again without broadband in the network loop, still can't print to my network printers...

Comment: I wonder if the real issue is that your tablet dosen't have drivers for your printers?

Comment: The lack of a broadband connection giving you the "limited connectivity" message won't stop local network access so your printers should work once you have set them up. If it still fails, do the printers and you tablet have USB ports?

Comment: Uuuh. I always thought "Limited connectivity" was when `Your computer's request for an IP address went unanswered`. See [ask Leo](http://ask-leo.com/what_is_limited_connectivity_and_how_do_i_fix_it.html). So that would also mean no local network. It all depends on which IP address he got or has set.

Comment: @Rik, I get the limited connectivity message all the time on Win7 PCs at work that are networked successfully but are not allowed internet access (no physical router). Trust me, getting the message does not mean the LAN is definitely not working.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution if it's available would be to use one of the PCs to create an ad-hoc Wifi network, and then use that to bridge the connection to the wired network. Obviously this requires a Wifi card in one of the machines you're using on the network.

The Microsoft guide for doing so is here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-vista/create-a-network-bridge

The above guide is technically for Vista rather than Windows 8 - though the only difference should be in how you launch Control Panel. Easy way to do that is to open the start menu and start typing "Control Panel" - the shortcut should appear for you.

Comment: Thank you but to avoid my original post appearing overly complex, I omitted a point that my tablet already connects through wifi to my home broadband on a computer that is entirely separate to my office network.  If I try and link my tablet through an additional WiFi card on my office network I will lose my internet and email on Wifi through my home broadband!!  Now if there is a way of linking my office network to my home broadband other than running a 50' cable from one end of the house to the other.? A Wifi USB 'dongle' - will that do the trick as the PC's don't have internal WiFi adapters?

Comment: Yeah, connecting two networks far apart from each other is a complete separate question. You could look at those LAN over power-plugs to use your existing power lines to connect the two networks. There are also Wifi-routers who have a *client mode* to act as a client to another Wifi-router and distribute its signal further but this function is seldom seen in normal home Wifi-routers.

Answer (score 0):

What about the USB cable that came with your tablet? Plug that into one of the PCs and you should have access to the printers as long as you install some kind of printing app on the tablet, no?

Some of the apps in Google Play claim to support USB printing without a PC... see "Printer Share Mobile Print" free to try!

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynamixsoftware.printershare

Comment: Thank you. USB works, at the moment just with one printer through it's USB port (that I didn't realise it had :-o) - will try through another PC as you suggest if I need to use both printers..

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a [USB to Ethernet dongle](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb%20to%20ethernet%20adapter). It would allow you to connect your USB only tablet to the wired network, no wifi or wireless required.